# iAds crash in AdWhirl

Tags: iphone, iad, adwhirl

I'm implementing AdWhirl for the first time, and it is using iAds, AdMob, and MillennialMedia.  AdMob and MillenialMedia seem to work perfectly fine.

iAds load, display, and refresh just fine in my PlayViewController, but when I click the back button to go out to the main menu, the simulator crashes, with no error printed to the Console and no "_kill" message sent to XCode when running the app with Breakpoints On in Build and Debug.

If it's an AdMob or MillenialMedia ad showing, I can click the back button and return to the main menu with no problem. And can go back in to the PlayViewController and load a new ad with no problem.

Any ideas how to prevent this issue that seems tied to the iAds?
Perhaps it is something to do with iAds having a built-in timer to refresh the ad?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved it to the main ViewController and this issue is no longer happening.

However, since the ads are now started in the mainViewController but only displayed while in the PlayViewController, I am trying to find a way to tell AdWhirl to stop pulling ads when the player is on the main menu.  It auto refreshes and keeps pulling ads even when I use self.adView = nil;

Comment: I added the ad like this:
self.adView = [AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:self.adView];

And removed it like this:
[self.adView removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked the iAd Framework role ..if it's not weak make it weak that to make it not crash on the prior ios4